# Вычисление суммы со скидкой

Tags: jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь вычислить скидку, и вывести сумму с учетом скидки если введен код на скидку. Если же код не ввели то сумма остаётся прежней.

Я вот тут намудрил, и код на половину не работоспособен.

```
            $(function(){
                $('#price').bind('input', function(){
                    var summary = $('#price').val() ? $('#price').val() : 0;
                    $('#summary').html('Итого к оплате: ' + summary + ' рублей');

                    $('#card').bind('input', function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "{{ url('/cards/check') }}",
                            data: {
                                number: $('#card').val(),
                                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                            },
                            success: function(card){
                                if (card.number){
                                    summary = summary / card.percent * 100;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $('#summary').html('Итого к оплате: ' + summary + ' рублей');
                });
            });
```

Нужна помощь знатоков.

Comment: card.percent - это размер скидки в процентах?

Comment: @qzavyer именно.

Comment: то есть если сумма 1200 и скидка 50 процентов, то итог будет 1200/50*100=2400... Похоже в магазинах именно таким алгоритмом и пользуются. Вам нужно вычислять как-то так: `summary = summary * (1 - card.percent / 100)`

Comment: @qzavyer а как выводить всё это ? просто то что сейчас есть не работает.

Answer (score 1):

javascript выполняется асинхронно, то есть строка `$('#summary').html('Итого к оплате: ' + summary + ' рублей');` выполнится раньше чем ajax запрос, чтобы получить вывод после выполнения запроса вставьте его в success:

```
$(function(){
    $('#price').bind('input', function(){
        var summary = $('#price').val() ? $('#price').val() : 0;
        $('#summary').html('Итого к оплате: ' + summary + ' рублей');
        $('#card').bind('input', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "{{ url('/cards/check') }}",
                data: {
                    number: $('#card').val(),
                    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                success: function(card){
                    if (card.number){
                        summary = summary * (1 - card.percent / 100);
                    }
                    $('#summary').html('Итого к оплате: ' + summary + ' рублей');
                }
            });
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Можно вопрос ? А почему ajax запрос выполняется 3 раза подряд ?

Comment: Каждый раз когда вы меняете значение поля card. Если нужно, чтобы срабатывало только по окончании ввода (что логично) нужно изменить отслеживаемое событие с input на change